# how can i solve this sigmoid function in coursera?

Tags: python

how can i solve this?

> 2.2 - Computing the Sigmoid
> Amazing! You just implemented a linear function. TensorFlow offers a variety of commonly used neural network functions like tf.sigmoid and tf.softmax.
> For this exercise, compute the sigmoid of z.

In this exercise, you will: Cast your tensor to type float32 using tf.cast, then compute the sigmoid using tf.keras.activations.sigmoid.

**Exercise 2 - sigmoid**
Implement the sigmoid function below. You should use the following:

```
tf.cast("...", tf.float32)
tf.keras.activations.sigmoid("...")
```

```py
# GRADED FUNCTION: sigmoid
def sigmoid(z):
    
    """
    Computes the sigmoid of z
    
    Arguments:
    z -- input value, scalar or vector
    
    Returns: 
    a -- (tf.float32) the sigmoid of z
    """
    # tf.keras.activations.sigmoid requires float16, float32, float64, complex64, or complex128.
    
    # (approx. 2 lines)
    # z = ...
    # a = ...
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    return a
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should figure out your assignment by yourself.. But it is written in the task:

tf.cast("...", tf.float32) tf.keras.activations.sigmoid("...")

They tell you everything by this line. So the solution looks almost like this:

```
def sigmoid(z):

    """
    Computes the sigmoid of z

    Arguments:
    z -- input value, scalar or vector

    Returns: 
    a -- (tf.float32) the sigmoid of z
    """
    # tf.keras.activations.sigmoid requires float16, float32, float64, complex64,     or complex128.

    # (approx. 2 lines)
    # z = ...
    # a = ...
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    z = tf.cast(z, tf.float32)
    a = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(INSERT Z VARIABLE HERE)

    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    return a
```

You need to make small adjustment to the code, hope you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

This very easy Just google it otherwise See this below code it might help in your problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-z))
print(sigmoid(0.5))
```